# cloud computing simulation environment for project

Tags: java, cloud, simulation

I am an Engineering final year student. I am doing project in cloud computing. I have confident idea about the concept. But i don't know how to simulate the concept in cloud. For PG student level **Which cloud computing simulation environment is easy to use?** Kindly give your 
valuable suggestion. ( Now i am implementing the concept in java )

Comment: So are you trying to build a cloud or build something and put it in a cloud?

Comment: Build something and put it in a cloud @Kevin Bowersox

Comment: about 2 ages ago, i was working with windows azure, there was built-in "cloud-environment" in visual studio, but i dont know, if there is something comparable for java...

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at OpenShift, its free and very easy to use if your familiar with Unix/Git.  I host my blog there on a Java/Unix/MySql stack and have been very satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I recommend you to understand the difference between an IaaS and a PaaS. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing#Service_models) is always a good place where you can find this information. Maybe you could compare both cloud computer models.

You will see that on PaaS is much easier start with a service since you don't need to install, neither to configure anything. Usually, you just need a button to make available a specific service and not a lot of steps to deploy your application.

You should look for the "How to start" of different PaaS providers. You can start for this [How to start tutorial](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/10/how-to-start-on-cloudbees.html) and after this, look for similar guides and compare the most important providers. You could see that it is really easy start working on this cloud model.

Answer (score 1):

Agree: PaaS might be a good starting point. I don't have any experience with Java though, a quick Google search: http://www.cloudbees.com/ might be something.

If you want to go a bit deeper, you should try out Amazon's EC2. I believe they have done a very good job, plus they offer a free tier for one year.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build cloud computing simulations in Java, take a look at [CloudSim Plus](http://cloudsimplus.org). It is a modern, full-featured, highly extensible and easier-to-use Java 8 Framework for Modeling and Simulation of Cloud Computing Infrastructures and Services.

It is an actively maintained, totally re-designed, better organized and largely documented project. It has a large number of exclusive features and is the only cloud simulation framework available at maven central.

Some of its main characteristics and features include:

1. [Vertical VM Scaling](https://github.com/manoelcampos/cloudsim-plus/blob/master/cloudsim-plus-examples/src/main/java/org/cloudsimplus/examples/VerticalVmScalingExample.java) 
   that performs on-demand up and down allocation of VM resources such as Ram, Bandwidth and PEs (CPUs).
2. [Horizontal VM scaling](https://github.com/manoelcampos/cloudsim-plus/blob/master/cloudsim-plus-examples/src/main/java/org/cloudsimplus/examples/LoadBalancerByHorizontalVmScalingExample.java), allowing dynamic creation of VMs according to an overload condition. Such a condition is defined by a predicate that can check different VM resources usage such as CPU, RAM or BW.
3. [Parallel execution of simulations](https://github.com/manoelcampos/cloudsim-plus/blob/master/cloudsim-plus-examples/src/main/java/org/cloudsimplus/examples/ParallelSimulationsExample.java), allowing several simulations to be run simultaneously, in a isolated way, inside a multi-core computer.
4. [Listeners](https://github.com/manoelcampos/cloudsim-plus/blob/master/cloudsim-plus-examples/src/main/java/org/cloudsimplus/examples/listeners/) to enable simulation monitoring.
5. Classes and interfaces to allow implementation of [heuristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic) such as 
   [Tabu Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabu_search), [Simulated Annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing), 
   [Ant Colony Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms) and so on. See an [example using Simulated Annealing here](https://github.com/manoelcampos/cloudsim-plus/blob/master/cloudsim-plus-examples/src/main/java/org/cloudsimplus/examples/DatacenterBrokerHeuristicExample.java).